# c# Check if Last item in stack equals X before pushing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stack, undo-redo

so I hope my question makes sense, but I'm working on a basic undo/redo system in Unity, and I am trying to prevent "empty" iterations from being added (basically if an object hasn't changed position).

I'm using the typical stack workflow for Undo/Redo systems, and here is my method for adding a method to the undo stack:

```
public static void AddAction(UndoableChange action)
{
    redoStack.Clear();
    undoStack.Push(action);
}
```

I am adding undoable changes when an object is "selected" on the frame that the mouse is down and then again when the mouse is up.  But before I do that, I want to make sure that it's not recording me just clicking on the screen randomly (that leads to me having to undo multiple times before the actual undo has been called).
What would the syntax be for checking if the last/most recent item in a stack does not equal the UndoableChange I am trying to push?

I have tried this, but it's still registering "empty" clicks:

```
public static void AddAction(UndoableChange action)
{
    if (undoStack.Count >0 && undoStack.Peek().Equals(action))
        return;

    redoStack.Clear();
    undoStack.Push(action);
}
```

This seems like it should be relatively simple.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Full Script Below**

```
    public struct ObjectState
{
    // The transform this data belongs to
    private Transform transform;

    private Vector3 localPosition;
    private Quaternion localRotation;
    private Vector3 localScale;

    private bool active;

    public ObjectState(GameObject obj)
    {
        transform = obj.transform;
        localPosition = transform.localPosition;
        localRotation = transform.localRotation;
        localScale = transform.localScale;

        active = obj.activeSelf;
    }

    public void Apply()
    {
        transform.localPosition = localPosition;
        transform.localRotation = localRotation;
        transform.localScale = localScale;

        transform.gameObject.SetActive(active);
    }
}
public struct UndoableChange
{
    private ObjectState _before;
    private ObjectState _after;

    public UndoableChange(ObjectState before, ObjectState after)
    {
        _before = before;
        _after = after;
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        _before.Apply();
    }

    public void Redo()
    {
        _after.Apply();
    }
}

public static class UndoRedoControls
{
    private static Stack<UndoableChange> undoStack = new Stack<UndoableChange>();
    private static Stack<UndoableChange> redoStack = new Stack<UndoableChange>();

    public static void Undo()
    {
        if (undoStack.Count == 0) return;

        var lastAction = undoStack.Pop();

        lastAction.Undo();

        redoStack.Push(lastAction);
        Debug.Log("UNDOING");
    }

    public static void Redo()
    {
        if (redoStack.Count == 0) return;

        var lastAction = redoStack.Pop();

        lastAction.Redo();

        undoStack.Push(lastAction);
        Debug.Log("REDOING");
    }

    public static void AddAction(UndoableChange action)
    {
        if (undoStack.Count >0 && undoStack.Peek().Equals(action))
            return;

        redoStack.Clear();
        undoStack.Push(action);
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to implement `Equals` otherwise by default it just uses reference equality and since you register always a new `UndoableChange` instance it will never be equal to any other instance already in the stack

Comment: @derHugo Thanks for the reply!  I think I understand what you're saying, but is there an alternative that would actually do what I'm looking for? To check specifically if the _values_ of the most recent UndoableChange equals that of the last UndoableChange in the stack, not if an UndoableChange is an UndoableChange, lol

Comment: There is a nuget package called object comparer that you can use, it compares values rather than references, while it will increase the project footprint it will achieve what you are looking for. [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ObjectsComparer/) Do note that this package has not been updated since November of 2019, Although I see no problems with it, newer versions of .NET might cause some friction.

Comment: @anand_v.singh Good find!  Because I'm using Unity though, I don't think that will work.  Thanks though!  I'm surprised there's no syntax for doing this already.

Comment: @JudahMantell I have no experience in unity and am not sure about the nuget situation there, I would suggest that you then implement the IComparable<T> in your classes.

Comment: @anand_v.singh IComparable can of course be used .. you can however also simply implement any method that is capable of comparing two instances ;)

Comment: @anand_v.singh also I think we both rater ment `IEquatable<T>` ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding--I'm not the most advanced c# user--is there a snippet I can use to do this, or is there more to it?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by default `Equals` checks for **reference equality** for classes which is not what you want to do and what afaik for `struct` fails per default since they are value types and therefore never the same instance.

You would rather want to see whether the `before` and `after` value are different.

You can of course implement any method checking the equality but the best practice is implementing [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1)

Therefore you could use something like e.g.

```
public struct ObjectState : IEquatable<ObjectState>
{
    // The transform this data belongs to
    public readonly Transform transform;

    private readonly Vector3 localPosition;
    private readonly Quaternion localRotation;
    private readonly Vector3 localScale;

    private readonly bool active;

    public ObjectState(GameObject obj)
    {
        transform = obj.transform;
        localPosition = transform.localPosition;
        localRotation = transform.localRotation;
        localScale = transform.localScale;

        active = obj.activeSelf;
    }

    public void Apply()
    {
        transform.localPosition = localPosition;
        transform.localRotation = localRotation;
        transform.localScale = localScale;

        transform.gameObject.SetActive(active);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is ObjectState objState)) return false;
        return Equals(objState);
    }

    public bool Equals(ObjectState other)
    { 
        if(other.transform != transform) return false;

        // For now using the approximations Unity uses by default
        // with precision of 0.00001
        return other.localPosition == localPosition && other.localRotation == localRotation && other.localScale == localScale;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(ObjectState a, ObjectState b)
    {  
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(ObjectState a, ObjectState b)
    {
        return !a.Equals(b); 
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = transform.GetHashCode();
            hash = 31 * hash + localPosition.GetHashCode();
            hash = 31 * hash + localRotation.GetHashCode();
            return 31 * hash + localScale.GetHashCode(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can actually check whether two `ObjectState` instances are equal.

Now you can use this

```
public struct UndoableChange : IEquatable<UndoableChange>
{
    private ObjectState _before;
    private ObjectState _after;

    // Check if this is a valid action
    // It refers to the same object
    // and actually something was changed
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return _before.transform == _after.transform && _before != _after;
    }

    public UndoableChange(ObjectState before, ObjectState after)
    {
        _before = before;
        _after = after;
    }

    public void Undo()
    {
        _before.Apply();
    }

    public void Redo()
    {
        _after.Apply();
    }

    public override bool Equals (object obj)
    {
        if(!(obj is UndoableChange other)) return false;
        return Equals (other);
    }

    public bool Equals (UndoableChange other)
    {
        return other._before == _before && other._after == _after;
    }

    public static bool operator ==(UndoableChange a, UndoableChange b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(UndoableChange a, UndoableChange b)
    {
        return !a.Equals(b);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode ()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return _before.GetHashCode() * 31 + _after.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can check two things

```
if(action.IsValid())
```

and

```
if(undoStack.Peek() != action)
```